# How to animate the particle hair size?

Tags: animation, particles, transforms, hair

I have made a sphere and assigned a hair particle system. I'd like to scale the hair particles in one area when higher than that of another area and would like to animate that too.

**Q:** How to animate the particle hair size?

Comment: U can animate particle size by hitting i key in the scale input box

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can easily animate particle scale:

In your particle settings, under "Render" right-click on "Scale" and choose `insert keyframe`. Alternatively, you can click on the small dot right to the box.

Then, go forward in your timeline, insert a new value for "Scale" and again, insert a keyframe.

[image]

This may result in something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click the scale value, then click insert keyframe. Move to another frame, then edit the scale value. Right-click the value, then add another keyframe. This will animate its size.